# Trying to print an element from a sorted list in python

Tags: python, list

I am trying print an element that is in a list that has been sorted and stored into a variable. I want to be able to print the element that is stored in the list, in this case ice cream flavors, based on user input. This is for an assignment for a class. I feel I have most of the code working and I am able to call elements from the dictionary I created but not my list.

```
#Create flavor list

flavorList = ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry','Pistachio','Butter Pecan', 'Cookie Dough', 'Neapolitan']

flavorList[6] = 'Tiramisu' #Change value of one flavor

flavorInput = input("Add additional flavor of your choice: ")

flavorList.append(flavorInput) #Sort list in alphabetical order
sorted_flavors = sorted(flavorList)
print('What flavor of ice cream would you like?') 

#Indexes the flavor starting from 1
for flavIndex, sorted_flavors in enumerate (sorted_flavors, start=1):
    print(flavIndex, sorted_flavors)

flavorSelection = input('Select numbers 1-8 for your desired flavor: ')
flavorSelection = int(flavorSelection) #stores user flavor selection in a variable
theFlavor = flavorSelection 
theFlavor = theFlavor -1
theFlavor = int(theFlavor)

#Create dictionaries for flavor prices and sizes
conePrices = dict(S='$1.50', M='$2.50', L='$3.50')
coneSizes = dict(S='Tiny', M='Regular Joe', L='Big Fella')

sizeSelection = input('What size would you like?: \n' + "Press S for small, M for Medium and L for Large:")
sizeSelection = sizeSelection.upper()
sizeSelection = str(sizeSelection)
theSize = coneSizes[sizeSelection]
thePrice = conePrices[sizeSelection]
print('Okay your '+ theSize, sorted_flavors[theFlavor] + 'ice cream costs ' + thePrice + '.')
print( 'Please wait just a moment and your order will arrive shortly... ')
```

Answer (score 0):

In this line

```
#Indexes the flavor starting from 1
for flavIndex, *sorted_flavors* in enumerate (sorted_flavors, start=1):
    print(flavIndex, sorted_flavors)
```

You are overwriting the value of `sorted_flavors` with the value of a string contained within `sorted_flavors`. It's actually sort of weird that you code still even works! Anyways, if you replace this with

```
#Indexes the flavor starting from 1
for flavIndex, flavor in enumerate (sorted_flavors, start=1):
    print(flavIndex, flavor)
```

It works. The entire fixed code is below.

```
#Create flavor list

flavorList = ['Vanilla', 'Chocolate', 'Strawberry','Pistachio','Butter Pecan', 'Cookie Dough', 'Neapolitan']

flavorList[6] = 'Tiramisu' #Change value of one flavor

flavorInput = input("Add additional flavor of your choice: ")

flavorList.append(flavorInput) #Sort list in alphabetical order
sorted_flavors = sorted(flavorList)
print('What flavor of ice cream would you like?') 

#Indexes the flavor starting from 1
for flavIndex, flavor in enumerate (sorted_flavors, start=1):
    print(flavIndex, flavor)


flavorSelection = int(input('Select numbers 1-8 for your desired flavor: ')) - 1

#Create dictionaries for flavor prices and sizes
conePrices = dict(S='$1.50', M='$2.50', L='$3.50')
coneSizes = dict(S='Tiny', M='Regular Joe', L='Big Fella')


sizeSelection = input('What size would you like?: \n' + "Press S for small, M for Medium and L for Large:")
sizeSelection = sizeSelection.upper()
theSize = coneSizes[sizeSelection]
thePrice = conePrices[sizeSelection]
print('Okay your '+ theSize + ' ' + sorted_flavors[flavorSelection] + ' ice cream costs ' + thePrice + '.')
print( 'Please wait just a moment and your order will arrive shortly... ')
```